# Dijit maxLength via dojo constraint language?

Tags: javascript, constraints, dojo, dijit.form

I am working on a project where I am trying to map constraints onto Dijit controls in an XSLT to HTML.

One such constraint is the maximum length of a text field.
However, I cannot find such a constraint within the Dojo constraint language.

Does such a constraint (excluding a RegEx one) exist that I have missed in my example below?

```
    <label for="shortField">shortField </label>
    <input id="shortField" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/ValidationTextBox"
        data-dojo-props = "name: 'shortField',
                           width:400,
                           height:150,
                           value: '1234567890',
                           required: true,
                           constraints: { max:10, maxLength:10, length:10, size:10 }
        " />
```

For consistency, I would prefer to make use of a constraint rather than setting the maxLength property of the _TextBoxMixin.

(Unfortunately, the setting of a regex in the constraints is also undesirable, as that may be overridden later, outside of my control.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that no such constraint exists. furthermore, since I found out that I additionally need to validate the minimum length, I have chosen the solution of subclassing the Dijit.Form.ValidationTextBox.

This is the implementation I have chosen for the isValid method ,which reads from the constraints, so I can keep my generating XSL code consistent. )

```
    isValid : function(){
                var ancestorsValid = this.inherited(arguments);

                if(ancestorsValid){
                    //Acquire only meaningful validation boundaries.
                    var minLength = this.constraints && this.constraints.minLength ? Number(this.constraints.minLength) : null;
                    var maxLength = this.constraints && this.constraints.maxLength ? Number(this.constraints.maxLength) : null;

                    //Validate min and max if present.
                    return  ((minLength === null) || this.value.length >= minLength) &&
                            ((maxLength === null) || this.value.length <= maxLength);

                }
                return false;
            }
```